# Use PHP to convert Texas State Plane to decimal

Tags: coordinate-system, php

I'm trying to find a PHP function to convert a state plane coordinate to decimal.

For example,

NAD_1983_stateplane_texas_south_fips_4205_feet (EPSG:102741)

to

WGS84 (EPSG:4326)... or NAD83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try proj4php.

https://github.com/proj4php/proj4php

Then just define your point and its projection (EPSG:102741) and pass that into a transform statement with your intended projection (EPSG:4326).

Comment: This is exactly it, I wrote a php page awhile back using proj4js that does that transformation (tx state plane south to wgs84) from either a single coordinate or a csv that you can export from a data collector.  http://gislab.net/mapping/

Comment: On that page, is proj4js doing the projection then?  This question is about actually doing it within PHP

Comment: This library worked well. I could even load custom proj4 definitions. This must be the easiest way to do any coordinate conversion. Thanks Thomas

Comment: it is a php page, it just happens to use proj4js instead of proj4php

Comment: it appears the proj4php library doesn't convert nad27 to nad83 correctly. it did convert nad27 state plane coordinate to nad27 decimal correctly. now I just have to convert nad27 to nad83 or wgs84...

Comment: Please report those issues on their github page so that they are aware and can make the appropriate change.